# Django: How to read info from custom radio select in view

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-models

So yesterday I spent whole day customizing star-rating ("radio-button-ish"). Now I don't want to abandon my css masterpiece (I am not much of a front-end guy so this was real pain for me), but it looks like that my approach to the problem wasn't correct. Html code is quite simple:

```
<div class="col-md-5 mb-0 mt-3">
    <div id="rating">
        <input type="radio" name="star" id="star1"><label for="star1"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" id="star2"><label for="star2"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" id="star3"><label for="star3"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" id="star4"><label for="star4"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" id="star5"><label for="star5"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, is there a way to simply read from this choice and then use it in my view?
The situation is, normally I would probably use Field in form with choices but the design would be lost. Do you see a simple solution? Or is there a way of customizing a ChoiceField with widget RadioSelect into the same form, so i can use the name, id just like in above html code?

Note: this is my first django project, pardon me if it is a complete nonsense or I missed something basic..

Answer (score 0):

you can put this code inside your form.

here the field name is star. so you if you access field value of star, then you should get the selected value

small note: in your code this snippent 'id="rating"' is unnecessary